# Why does Exodus 12:40 say the Israelites lived in Egypt and Canaan in Septuagint if Canaan is Israel, aren’t Egypt and Canaan two different places?

Tags: exodus

Exodus 12:40 of the Septuagint says

> Now the length of time the Israelite people lived in Egypt and Canaan

How could they have lived in Canaan if Canaan was part of the promised land

Answer (score 1):

**Why does Exodus 12:40 say the Israelites lived in Egypt and Canaan in Septuagint if Canaan is Israel, aren’t Egypt and Canaan two different places?**

Because the 430 years begins when Abraham received the promise from God and entered the promise land. It ended when his descendants, the Israelites, left Egypt. This is exactly the understanding that Paul has of the 430 years:

> Galatians 3:16-17 16 **Now the promises were made to Abraham and to his offspring.** It does not say, “And to offsprings,” referring to many, but referring to one, “And to your offspring,” who is Christ. 17 This is what I mean: **the law, which came 430 years afterward,** does not annul a covenant previously ratified by God, so as to make the promise void.

Here's a fun video (12:31) explaining all the math:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FF0F8YjT1og&t=122s&ab_channel=NathanH83

Comment: +1. Good answer.

Comment: Do you know why the other translations say "the length the Israelite people lived in Egypt was 430 years" even though they lived in Egypt 215 years?

Comment: @exodus, because they are all based on the Masoretic text which came 1200 years after the LXX and approx  1000 years after Christ.

Comment: @exodus, check the video. It's pretty interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Why does Exodus 12:40 say the Israelites lived in Egypt and Canaan in Septuagint if Canaan is Israel, aren’t Egypt and Canaan two different places?

The children of ISRAEL are mentioned, not the children of ABRAHAM. ISRAEL was the new name given to Jacob before he even entered Canaan. The descendants of Israel would therefore be the descendants of Jacob. Jacob was over 40 before there were any children of Israel. The children of Israel (Jacob) traveled into Egypt during the 7-year famine that Jacob's son Joseph helped Egypt survive.

Some translations have variations of Exodus 12:40 that include Egypt and Canaan and other translations vary to include Jacob, Abraham, and Issac. But the KJV has the children of Israel and not the children (descendants) of Abraham.

The children of Israel do not include Abraham and Issac.